# How to assign material index?

Tags: materials

I have an object in Blender that I want to export to a game and I must assign two different materials (textures) to it, which I know how to do. However I also need to inform the game which index is associated with the given texture (0 and 1). How can I assign the different indices to the two materials?

Answer (score 0):

Create two materials slots (plus icon on the material menu) and assign them on the selected faces.

First slot will have index of 0, second material will have index of 1 (and third mat = 2, fourth = 3, ......)

[image]